# Split payments to multiple vendors by stripe api?

Tags: api, stripe-payments, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments, stripe-connect

I am `building` a `website` for event planners where vendor register there services and consumer book there services. Consumers can select multiple vendors for their events. I have to get `payment` from user and split to **`multiple vendors`**. Using `paypal` I have adaptive payments method, but what should I do **`stripe payments`**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34284090/how-split-payments-by-stripe-api

Comment: Indeed, Connect is Stripe's product for accepting payments on behalf of others and (optionally) split funds between them and yourself. The linked answer above explains this in more details.

Comment: @Ywain But I want to split between multiple service providers(vendors).

Comment: At the moment, Connect only lets you split a payment between yourself and one third-party. Stripe is looking to allow for more complex payment flows where a payment could be split with multiple third-parties, but that's not possible just yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have worked on Stripe simple payment as well as Stripe connect. I have used both stripe `Manged account` and Stripe `Standalone accounts`.
At the moment, Connect only lets you `split a payment between yourself and one third-party`. Stripe is looking to allow for more complex payment flows where a payment could be split with multiple third-parties, but that's not possible just yet.

Comment: is this still the case?